# MVC 5 - Why is my linq code selecting an entire query instead of a single value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Here is an example of what some locations look like in my database:

ID, DepartmentId, LocationName

8,2,Main Warehouse

12,2, Filter Cellar

When I use the following code, it grabs the entire query and puts it as the value for my HTML dropdown list.

```
public ActionResult GetLocations(int id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> locations = new List<SelectListItem>();
        //based on the  input coming to this method ( product id)
        var incident = new AccidentSupervisorViewModel();
        incident.Locations = DB.Locations.ToList().Select(i => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = i.LocationName,
                Value = i.DepartmentId.ToString()
            }      
        ).Where(i => i.Value == id.ToString());

        var departmentId = from loc in DB.Locations where loc.DepartmentId == id select loc.DepartmentId;

        for (var x = 0; x < incident.Locations.Count(); x++) {
            locations.Add(new SelectListItem {
                Text = incident.Locations.ElementAt(x).Text,
                Value = departmentId.ToString()
            });
        }
        return Json(locations,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

[image]

This is most likely happening because I have a syntax error, but I haven't used linq much for queries so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you've not 'done' anything with the `IQueryable<T>` that is generated by Linq. Linq generates the query **but doesn't do anything with it until the `IQueryable<T>` or other `IEnumerable` is iterated over**. See [Deferred Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-example) and [Classification of Standard Query Operators by Manner of Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution).

In your case, since you're looking for a single value, you'll need to pop in the following line after you first declare `departmentId`:

```
var department = departmentId.FirstOrDefault();
```

This will pop out the first or default value from the `IQueryable<T>` you made.